# Как правильно удалять связанные объекты в ManyToMany?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Возникла сл проблема:

При удалении дочернего объекта удаляется родительский.
Как это исправить.Т.е

У Worker есть List должностей(Должность это отдельная сущность).Как при удалении должности удалить ее из листа Worker.И как при удалении объекта Worker сохранить должность т.е объект Position?

Все гетеры и сетеры и конструкторы убрал.Использую Spring Boot+Spring Data+Hibernate

**Это Worker**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "worker")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Worker implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 256)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 256)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber")
    private Long phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "shiftSalary", nullable = true)
    private Long shiftSalary;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE }, mappedBy="workerList")
    private List<Position> allPosition;

    @Column(name = "countShift", nullable = true)
    private Long countShift;

    @Column(name = "salary", nullable = true)
    private Long salary;
```

**Это Position**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "jobName")
    private String jobName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    @JoinTable(name = "permissions_allPosition",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "position_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")})
    private List<Worker> workerList;
```

Comment: Привет. Если ответ помог, не забудь за него проголосовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно иначе составить отношение сущностей:

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

    //...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private final Set<Position> positions = new HashSet<>();

    @PrePersist
    public void addPositions() {
        positions.forEach(position -> position.getWorkers().add(this));
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void removePositions() {
        positions.forEach(position -> position.getWorkers().remove(this));
    }
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Position {

    //...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "position")
    private final Set<Worker> workers = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Worker> getWorkers() {
        return workers;
    }
    //...
}
```

Это **bidirectional ManyToMany**, поэтому в Worker'е нужны еще *вспомогательные* методы для добавления и удаления Позиций.

Для **unidirectional** вспомогательные методы не нужны.

См. [мануал](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many)

---

Я бы *bidirectional* не использовал - из-за него код усложняется, а преимущества, как у *bidirectional OneToMany*, отсутствуют (все равно будет задействована третья таблица связей типа `worker_position`).

А если понадобится получить список Воркеров для конкретной Позиции, то это легко сделать таким образом:

```
public interface WorkerRepository extend JpaRepository<Worker, Long> {
    List<Worker> findByPositions(Position position);
}
```

---

Рабочий [пример](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example9) с [тестами](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/test/java/restsdemo/example9).

Comment: спасибо помогло!Но неужели нельзя это сделать без сторонних методов?Конкретно с такой связью которая была у меня,при удалении позиции она автоматически удаляется из листа воркера но при удалении воркера удаляются все позиции которые есть в этом листе(я имею в виду ту связь которая была у меня изначально т.е в вопросе )

Comment: @Zaytsev_Dmitry нельзя. оно же не телепат, не знает какие у тебя методы. Ну, и как я написал, здесь лучше unidirectional использовать - доп. методы не нужны.

Comment: @Cepr0 вы пишите  это - " bidirectional ManyToMany, поэтому в Worker'е нужны еще вспомогательные методы для добавления и удаления Позиций."- но разве вы удаляете позицию? как по мне вы удаляете Worker-a из набора  Worker-ов в наборе position каждого Worker-а, в котором нужно удалить Worker-а, для того что бы, при удалении Worker-а, удалить его из набора Worker-ов в наборе position, и не удалять при етом саму positiopns.Просто ваш коментарий сбил меня с толку, потому что я как раз розбираюсь с етой темой.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
@PreRemove
private void removePositionsFromWorkers() {
    for (Worker w : workerList) {
        w.getAllPosition().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Само собой, должен быть соответсвующий геттер. Чтобы это работало позиции должны содержать актуальный список воркеров. Тоесть каждый раз когда добавляешь позицию к листу позиций воркера, нужно добавлять и воркера в лист воркеров позиции(обратная связь). Не будет работать с CascadeType.ALL